# How do you retrieve the changes made on a model instance before commited?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a simple little DB-model that allows me to easily store the changes made to a model instance as so called history-items. The whole idea is to have a single table for all the history-items so I used the [example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/generic_associations/generic_fk.html) for that from the sqlalchemy docs. To make this fully functional I of course need to some how retrieve the changes made to an instance itself. Is there an elegant way to aquire this from the instance itself or even the session?

I've already tried storing the changes while they are made via the `__setattr__` datamodel hook. And it did kind of work, but I'm still wondering if there is a "cleaner" way to this.

This is what the above mentioned approach looks like:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
from enum import IntEnum, unique
import json

from sqlalchemy import and_, event, inspect, Column,\
                       Integer, Text, Enum, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.orm import foreign, backref, remote, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


__all__ = (
    'HistoryItem',
)


Base = declarative_base()


class JSONEncodedDict(TypeDecorator):
    impl = VARCHAR

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value, default=str)

        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.loads(value)
        return value


class HistoryItem(Base):
    @unique
    class Types(IntEnum):
        CREATE = auto()
        EDIT   = auto()
        DELETE = auto()

        @classmethod
        def get_type(cls, obj):
            return {
                HasHistory.States.FRESH:   HistoryItem.Types.CREATE,
                HasHistory.States.EDITED:  HistoryItem.Types.EDIT,
                HasHistory.States.DELETED: HistoryItem.Types.DELETE,
            }[obj.current_state]

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Enum(Types))
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=lambda: datetime.now())
    diff = Column(JSONEncodedDict())

    target_discriminator = Column(String())
    target_id = Column(Integer())

    @property
    def target(self):
        return getattr(self, f"target_{self.target_discriminator}")

    @classmethod
    def build_for(cls, obj, user=None):
        assert isinstance(obj, HasHistory), "Can only build historyitems for models that have a history."

        type = HistoryItem.Type.get_type(obj)
        diff = obj.changes

        hi = HistoryItem(type=type, diff=diff)
        obj.history.append(hi)
        return hi


class HasHistory:
    @unique
    class States(IntEnum):
        FRESH   = auto()
        EDITED  = auto()
        DELETED = auto()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._changes = defaultdict(list)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__class__.__table__.c:
            self._changes.extend([getattr(self, name), value])
        return super().__setattr__(name, value)

    @property
    def changes(self):
        return {
            name: (changes[0], changes[1])
            for name, changes in self._changes.items()
        }

    @property
    def current_state(self):
        inspection = inspect(self)
        if inspection.transient:
            return HasHistory.States.FRESH
        elif inspection.deleted:
            return HasHistory.States.DELETED
        elif inspection.persistant:
            return HasHistory.States.EDITED


@event.listens_for(HasHistory, "mapper_configured", propagate=True)
def setup_listener(mapper, class_):
    discriminator = class_.__name__.lower()
    class_.history_discriminator = discriminator
    class_.history = relationship(
        HistoryItem,
        primaryjoin=and_(
            class_.id == foreign(remote(HistoryItem.target_id)),
            HistoryItem.target_discriminator == discriminator,
        ),
        backref=backref(
            f"target_{discriminator}",
            primaryjoin=remote(class_.id) == foreign(HistoryItem.target_id),
        ),
    )

    @event.listens_for(class_.history, "append")
    def append_history(self, history_item, event):
        history_item.target_discriminator = discriminator
```

Again, the approach does work (though admittedly it does require some more work on the JSONEncodedDict column type to make it compatible). But it still wonder if it is possible to do this in a "cleaner" fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, I found an answer to my question, and it seems I just wasn't looking hard enough. The `inspect` method from sqlalchemy generates a so called `InstanceState` object when called on a model instance. Said object contains an `ImmutableMapping` of all the db-related attributes on the instance in the form of a so called `AttributeState`. And from said `AttributeState`s you can fairly simply extract the history of the instance. The whole thing looks like the following:

```py
inspection = inspect(obj)
diff = dict()
for attr in inspection.attrs:
    field = attr.key
    if attr.history.has_changes():
        added, unchanged, deleted = attr.history
        diff[field] = {
            "to": [*added, *unchanged] or None,
            "from": [*deleted, *unchanged] or None,
        }
```

This code generates a dictionary named `diff` which contains the changes for all the fields that have changed. The resulting `diff` can be read the lines of:

> The `field` on the `obj` changed `from` to `to`.